# How to open an Intent (MapView) from the Main activity with menu in Android

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-manifest

Since I'm a newbie I don't know if I'll be explaning this correctly. But here goes it.

I'm trying from main Activity (MainFile.java) to open a Map as a new intent through a menu. Something like this...

```
switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case VIEW_AROUND:
            **Intent cityMap = new Intent(MainFile.this, Map.class);
            startActivity(cityMap);**
            return true;
        case EXIT:
            this.finish();
            return true;
        }
```

... and I already have set up thing on my manifest.xml with access to...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<activity android:name=".Map" />
```

... It worked fine with other File.class, but with the Map.class doesn't seem to be working.

Might it be a better way to approach it? Is it anywhere I should be looking for the issue?

I cannot think of anything else :(

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I forgot to mention that my program crashes when I run it after I click the menuitem.

Comment: Could you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

I just found a thread with just my problem and the solution.

This is the link: http://www.mail-archive.com/android-beginners@googlegroups.com/msg13138.html

And from the link this is pretty much what I did (in case you don't want to click through or the link breaks in the future):

> Well, it might have been something
>   wrong with the maps.jar. I created a
>   new project from scratch and
>   discovered that maps.jar in the sdk
>   version i'm using is very buggy and a
>   lot smaller than in the previous
>   version. For instance, i was unable to
>   compile my maps class when i created
>   an instance of the GeoPoint class.
>   Anyway, the buggy version of the
>   maps.jar is in the sdk 1.5_r2. I'm now
>   using the maps.jar found in the sdk
>   1.5_r1 and everything works smoothly :)

Maybe someone else comes along this issue in the future.